# Can not programmatically send email using web service of MS Exchange Server 2010 SP2

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I got an app (C#) that send email using web service of MS Exchange Server 2010 SP2. It works fine before. But, just 2 weeks ago, I got the problem with it. Sometime the code can send an email but sometime it's not. I got the error message as below (full error message shows at the end).

```
The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server
```

My code is below.

```
string ewsUrl = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/ews/Exchange.asmx";
string userName = "xxxx";
string password = "xxxx";
string to = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
string cc = "xxxx@xxxx.com";

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = bodyHtml;
message.ToRecipients.Add(to);
message.CcRecipients.Add(cc);

message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

I don't know what went wrong. I believe that the URL is correct and it's work sometime and don't another time. I have search on the internet but don't found any solutions for this. **Is this something about server configuration?** I have talked to my IT guy but it seems that he got no idea about the web service. Please help me. The full error message is below.

```
The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(HttpWebRequest& request)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.CreateItem(Item item, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.Send()
```

Comment: What Port are you trying to connect to? "https://xxx.." implies 443 . IS that port accessible from your webserver?

Comment: Have you tried using the AutodiscoverUrl feature?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633699(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Do I have to specify port as well? My URL is just `"https://email.companydomain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx"`;

Comment: I have try AutodiscoverUrl feature but it getting worse. My server block the feature and error message suggest me to use AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback. Then I try it. But still no success. my Callback is below. 

`static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl)
        {
            return (redirectionUrl == "https://autodiscover-s.companydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml");
        }`

Is this correct? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    delegate(object sender1,
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
             System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
    { return true; };
```

I think you need to add the above code between `message.CcRecipients.Add(cc);`
and `message.SendAndSaveCopy();`

Comment: This completely bypasses Server Certificate validation, which can be dangerous depending on your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please tell me what the above code does? IS it OK to use? What Guvante mean by "bypass Server Certificate Validation"?? Thank you.

Comment: What @Guvante means is that the code above does no checks as to the validity of the certificate that you are given. As you can tell, that delegate always returns true so if somehow that information is incorrect, it won't be caught. It's a security risk. I would use it for testing, but not beyond that. There are articles out there on how to properly check certificates if this solves your problem.